# Objective C - Code sniffer

Tags: objective-c

I am looking for coding standard checker something like php_codesniffer (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.intro.php) for objective c.

Thanks,
Jose Antony

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check out [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/), there is also a [fork](http://github.com/andreberg/uncrustify) with better Objective-C support. If you want to integrate uncrustify into xcode, read the blog post: [Adding a code beautifier script to Xcode](http://hackertoys.com/2008/09/18/adding-a-code-beautifier-script-to-xcode/)

Comment: Good answer. Found a Uncrustify utility and documentation browser for Mac OS X: https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UncrustifyX

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM static analyzer is your answer.

In Xcode, you can use the *build and analyze* feature.

If you want to invoke it manually, see this [LLVM web page](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Comment: LLVM is not exactly the solution that I am looking for. LLVM is not capable of identifying problems in coding standars such trailing space. 2 tabs used instead of 1 tab. missing doc block. using "if(" instead of "if (" 
On such tool for CPP  is http://www.inspirel.com/vera/ce/demo.html

Comment: Makes sense -- Cation's answer is likely much more inline w/your needs.